# Usage of "tremendously"

Tags: word-usage

Can I use "tremendously" to indicate that the amount of research done in a
certain field has increased a lot like in the following sentence ?

"Smart grid research has increased tremendously in the last years, since it
has many applications to various problems in numerous areas."

Also, I'm not sure if "to" is the right preposition to use after the word "applications".

Thanks.

Comment: Your "tremendously" is an excellent choice for this *kind* of context, where you want to stress the sheer *extent* of the increase. But I have to say that it's just a little bit "colloquial" for more "formal" contexts, where [*...increased **significantly***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=research+has+increased+tremendously%2Cresearch+has+increased+significantly&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cresearch%20has%20increased%20tremendously%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresearch%20has%20increased%20significantly%3B%2Cc0) is a better fit.

Comment: ...maybe a personal opinion, but I think singular *...it has **application to** various problems in numerous areas* works better here too. But both these points are really about "writing advice".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica Thanks ! Very helpful advice.

Comment: Might consider "many applications towards various"

Comment: Adverbs such as 'tremendously', 'enormously', etc are somewhat 'excited' in tone and might be unsuitable for academic work.

Comment: A tremendous increase in y has occurred in the last years = this is better. Since basically, this boils down to editing....

Answer (score 2):

Your use of "tremendously" is correct. I liked the commenter's statement that in a formal context such as research papers, "significantly" seems more appropriately bland.

I think the common figure of speech is "applications in [fields]." But the phrase "many applications to various problems in numerous areas" seems repetitive with little added information. In describing the range of applications, what are you trying to say? If you just want to describe the quantity, I would say something like:

"Smart grid research has increased tremendously in the last years, since the applications are numerous."

If you want to describe the quantity, diversity, and perhaps profitability of the applications, you might say:

"Smart grid research has increased tremendously in the last years, since it has many lucrative applications in different fields."